# Mongo DB collection index is not working via API

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm having an entity called sample. I'm using the following code to drop and create index

```
mongoCollection.drop();
mongoCollection.ensureIndex("{name:1},{unique:true}")
```

This works when I do it via command prompt and run the test case. It creates duplicate records with same name.

This doesn't work when I ran via the Junit test case.

Code:

```
mongoCollection.save(entity);
```

Do I need to add any flush code? I don't think flush is required for ddl statements.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What version of the Java driver are you running?

Comment: build.sbt

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "uk.co.panaxiom" %% "play-jongo" % "1.0.1-jongo1.2",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.4.1" % "optional",
  "org.easytesting" % "fest-assert" % "1.4" % Test,
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % Test,
  cache,
  javaWs )